# fetching complex json from an object containing arraylist

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

i am trying to fetch a complex json in to the list . However if i try to fetch it says string is not a type of subtype CourseParent .

Following below is my model class which conntains another model

```
class Response {
  bool success;
  List<dynamic> errors;
  CourseParent courses;

  Response({this.success,this.errors,this.courses});

  factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Response(
        errors: map['errors'],
        success: map['success'],
        courses: map['body'],
    );
  }


  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {"success": success, "errors": errors,  "courses": courses, };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Response{ success: $success, errors: $errors , courses: $courses }';
  }

}

List<Response> profileFromJson(String jsonData) {
  final data = json.decode(jsonData);
  return List<Response>.from(data.map((item) => Response.fromJson(item)));
}



Response responseFromJson(String str) {
  final jsonData = json.decode(str);
  print("##-response"+jsonData.toString());

  return Response.fromJson(jsonData);
}


String responseToJson(Response data) {
  final jsonData = data.toJson();
  print("##--encoding"+json.encode(jsonData));
  return json.encode(jsonData);
}
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong here .

Course parent is an arraylist of object again

Comment: ```List<CourseParent> courses;``` you mean?

Comment: yes i modified it with as per your suggestion but it says type string is not a subtype of type List<CourseParent>

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse `body` manually. For example:

```dart
factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
  return Response(
    errors: map['errors'],
    success: map['success'],
    courses: map['body'].map((course) => CourseParent.fromJson(course)).toList(),
  );
}
```

Comment: this is list of Courseparent.... so should i use same approach as suggested bby you above ? CourseParent.fromJson(map['body'] @fartem